# How to change ManyToManyField widget to CheckboxSelectMultiple without overriding field definition in a ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms, many-to-many, django-widget

I have django `ModelForm` for model with ManyToManyField. I want to change widget for this field to`CheckboxSelectMultiple`. Can I do this without overriding a field in a form definition?

I constantly use code similar to this:

```
class MyModel(ModelForm):
    m2m_field = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset = SomeModel.objects.all(),
                                               widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

Is there other way to do this?

EDIT: I need this for Django 1.1.1 project

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another way to do this is doing it in the **init** of the ModelForm:

```
class MyModel(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['m2m_field'].widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()

    [...]
```

Answer (score 26):

If you're using Django 1.2+, you can use the `widgets` tuple in the inner Meta class.

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {'m2m_field': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple}
```

See [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets).

Comment: cool one! Thanks! unfortunetely in this project I use Django 1.1.1 so it won't help, anyway thanks for hint.